# Cannot figure out what input to use to get cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK method to work

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, opticalflow

I am trying to make a program in Python OpenCV where the user can define points on a video and optical flow would track it.

I tried to create my own coordinates in the form of a numpy array and tried to pass it into the calcOpticalFlowPyrLK method in OpenCV, but I get an error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, d, None, **lk_params)
error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp:593:
error: (-215) (npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0 in function calcOpticalFlowPyrLK
```

My code:

```
# params for ShiTomasi corner detection
feature_params = dict( maxCorners = 1,
                       qualityLevel = 0.01,
                       minDistance = 10,
                       blockSize = 7 )


p0 = np.array([[[348.0, 251.0]]])
# calculate optical flow
p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None, **lk_params)
```

I know that this is caused by the p0 variable because if I make p0 this:

```
p0 = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(old_gray, mask = mask_use, **feature_params)
```

And pass it into the calcOpticalFlowPyrLK parameter, it works. However I am trying to make a program in which the user defines the points, so if I create my own coordinates and pass p0 into the calcOpticalFlowPyrLK parameter like this:

```
d = np.array([[[348.0, 251.0]]])
p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, d, None, **lk_params)
```

Then I end up getting the error.

What numpy array do I have to create that the calcOpticalFlowPyrLK method would accept?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need `np.array([[[ .. ]]])`. What if you just use `[ .. ]`?

Comment: I used the np.array([[[ . . ]]]) because it is an output similar from goodFeaturesToDetect and thought I needed something similar to produce it. I tried it with [ . .  ] and it still produced the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> prevPts – vector of 2D points for which the flow needs to be found;
>   point coordinates must be single-precision floating-point numbers

so p0 must be a vector of 2D points:

```
p0 = [[x0, y0], [x1, y1], [x2, y2]]
```

So with just your one point, I would expect this to work:

```
p0 = [[348.0, 251.0]]
```

I think you've just used too many brackets and then too few.

Comment: I actually figured the solution to this problem, but our solutions look similar, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For opencv3 use 
`p0=np.array([[348.0, 251.0]],np.float32)`